# Image description web site

Tags: javascript, html, image, css, text

I would to add an image description to some images on my website. The descriptions are in `<div>` or `<p>` and I'm using jQuery. Let's assume I have:

**HTML**

```
<td><img href="aaa" onMouseOver="showMe()"><p id="descr">Description</p></td>
```

**CSS**

```
#descr{
    display: none;  
}
```

**JS**

```
function showMe()
{
    $("#descr").slideDown(1000);
}
```

Now the problem is that the description is showed but the content near it is displaced, shifted to make room to the new element. I'd like the description to appear as an overlay to what is below and to shift nothing, just like a dropdown description. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `position: absolute` it won't displace other elements. You'll need to play with the CSS to get it exactly where you want it to though - the position values are relative to the first parent with its own `position` value, other than static. Which is why if you just add `position: absolute` it'll probably be all mispositioned first.

Looking at the HTML you posted, you may want to apply `position: relative` to the `<td>` (like with `.image_table td`).

Comment: I'm still not able to place it where I wish but the position:absolute is doing its job. Thanks!!

Comment: No worries. Position absolute is quite a pain, because it's kinda like telling the browser "I'm in control". However, except for really complex examples it should be possible to get it to show properly. What's the problem now? We may be able to help

Comment: I'd like it to be centered with respect to the image... this "with respect to the image" is not being done by the browser, or better, by my code..

Comment: (I don't know if this will work) - assuming the `td` is the same size as the `img` (because the description is overlayed), and the description is just text (or inline/inline-block elements), you could make the description `width: 100%` (same width as the image) and set it to `text-align: center`

Comment: Mmh more or less it is getting right, the only thing is that the width and the text-align are with respect to the entire line of the table (a 2 elements per row table). How can I make it absolute with respect to the image?

Comment: Make sure the image and description are wrapped in a parent element (with nothing else in them). If the code you posted is really what you're using, make sure the `td` has a `position: relative`. Also, I just noticed you're using `id` for the description; it should probably be a class

Comment: Well man you are great! I used the position: relative on the <td> and all works greatly, http://luigitiburzi.com/books/ the third book is the one I'm debugging, now I'll add a description to all of them :-). I use an id because in the real code I pass the id and the description of the book to one js function, with jQuery and the id I get the particular book and I set the text to it. Only one thing, I'm curious because I don't understand the necessity of the position: relative to the <td> element, why is that instruction doing this effect? Of course, thanks, really thanks, for your help

Comment: It's just part of the CSS specification. Unfortunately, I'm not too sure all the details behind it :) . But for example, requiring a parent to have a non-static position attribute allows more flexibility in what the absolute element is "absolute to".

Comment: Well, many thanks again :-). Now I'll hide the text behind the dropdown panel and I'll start with the descriptions :-). Your help has been fantastic!